# Cannot throw instance of private member class? - Java

Tags: java, exception, static, inner-classes

What does this error mean, and why does it apply? I can't find much info with Google about member classes and static contexts, or what those mean, in a case that seems relevant to my situation.

Here's the error I'm getting:

`non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`

It points to this line, and at the `new` operator:

`throw new ParenthesisException();`

ParenthesisException is a private member class of the main class. I think the problem is probably related to that, but that's about all I can figure.

This is my definition of ParenthesisException. It is inside the main class definition: (I am sorry if the formatting is not very good)

```
private class ParenthesisException extends Throwable
{
    public ParenthesisException(){}
    public String strErrMsg()
    {
        return "ERROR: Every '(' needs a matching ')'";
    }
}
```

I find the error message rather cryptic. I would appreciate a brief explanation of "static contexts" and why the `new` operator isn't working for my member class, and how I can throw an instance of a private member class.

Comment: You need to post the code where the error is.  The private class doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had to guess what's going on based on the code fragment you've posted, the error is probably caused because you're trying to throw a `ParenthesisException` out of a `static` method.

In Java, classes defined inside of another class automatically store a pointer to the object inside which they were created.  That is `ParenthesisException` has an implicit pointer back to the enclosing class inside of which it was created with `new`.  This means that, in particular, you cannot construct a `new ParenthesisException` inside of a `static` method, because there is no `this` pointer that can be used to refer to the containing class.

To fix this, you should make `ParenthesisException` a `static` inner class like this:

```
private static class ParenthesisException extends Throwable
{
    public ParenthesisException(){}
    public String strErrMsg()
    {
        return "ERROR: Every '(' needs a matching ')'";
    }
}
```

This `static` after the `private` says that `ParenthesisException` does not hold a reference back to an enclosing object, which is probably what you wanted anyway.  It also means that you can create `new ParenthesisException`s inside of static methods.

Hope this guess is correct, and hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate your explanation! It seems to have worked for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is a bit confusing when you haven't seen it before, but it's exactly what it says: You can't use a non-static variable from a non-static context. Your main method and most likely any method in the class that contains your main method is static, so you can't use a non-static variable from it.

ParenthesisException is non-static because you haven't declared it as static, yet it is declared within your main class and called within a static method.

Don't declare this as an inner-class -- make your a new public class. You'll then be able to instantiate this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your main function is 'static context'. You can only call static function and there is not 'this'. When you try to create a new exception you effectively call `this.new ParenthesisException()`, because the exception is a inner class. But you can't do that. You need to create an istance of your main class and then create the exception object on that instance.

```
MainClass m = new MainClass();
throw m.new ParenthesisException();
```

Another solution is to define your exception as static class:

```
private static class ParenthesisException extends Throwable
```

Then you can instantiate it from static contexts, so you don't need an instance of the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Without code this is strictly a guess, but based on the error message I believe this would work.  If your `main` class is `Animal` then you need to instantiate `Animal` so inside of main if you do a simple...

`new Animal();` as the only line in `main`

then make a new method....

```
public Animal(){
    /* put code that used to be in main */
}
```

This will most likely fix your problem....again without full code this is strictly a guess, but based on what you said and the error I believe this will solve the problem.